# Jquery.DataTable drawn with header and body misaligned

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I'm trying to draw a table with datatables 1.9.4, but the header and body are misaligned. This is my first work with this wonderful tool, and because this I don't know where to start.

I have a template in my aplication where I need to display the table, and I can't change this display.

Below, in the link we have an example with the table inside the template.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayconfsbrito/faJkw/10/)

```
$(function(){
  var dt = $('#tabelainfo').dataTable( {
         "sDom": "Rlfrtip",
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bSort": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "bAutoWidth": false

    });

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: hi @mayconfsbrito please look this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/faJkw/16/), please remove unnecessary div

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks to be that you've manually added  all the extra html markup that dataTables will add itself - either that or your jsfiddle has the table html from after the table was initialized, which won't help people troubleshoot your problem.